# how to make docpad regenerate only the modified pages?

Tags: docpad

I have a simple site done in docpad, but all the time I make a small change I have wait for the all the pages to regenarate (around 40 sec). Any ideea how to make it regenerate only the modified pages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working on your site, you can run the command `docpad watch`.

*»To render standalone files with DocPad programatically (will output to stdout)«*

```
docpad render filePath
```

*»E.g. To render a markdown file and save the result to an output file, we would use:«*

```
docpad render inputMarkdownFile.html.md > outputMarkdownFile.html
```

*»To just watch your website for changes and re-generate whenever a change is made, use:«*
    docpad watch

Source: http://docpad.org/docs/cli